# How does one build a framework of sensors from nothing?

Tags: experimental-physics

I would like to understand how you can go from nothing to a framework of sensors you can use to try out things in physics/thermodynamics. That is, everything has to be bottoms up, nothing premade allowed (except maybe things like a lighter, screwdrivers, saws, hammers, but nothing that is already a sensor. So using a multimeter is cheating, for example, unless you build it yourself). Is there any book on this?

Comment: I don't see how this could usefully be answered here. You're essentially recapitulating the last 200 years of technological development. I suppose making a thermometer is simple enough, but good luck building your first transistor.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one build a framework of sensors from nothing?

For example, you can build a primitive ampere-meter using a compass like in the picture.

[image]

If you really want to get as primitive as possible see: [The Science Notebook](http://science-notebook.com/electricity04.html). The site teaches you even how to build a compass.